# Saving urls in an array and access it or display it

Tags: arrays, swift, url

I'm not able to save multiple urls in an array any way to solve this problem , thanks in advance

```
let audioUrl = NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")
```

Comment: So what's your final goal?

Comment: to use it to display the stored data available , and to download the available  songs from a website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make `NSURL` array then you have to convert every `String` to `NSURL` first then you can add it to `NSURL` array and you can do it this way:

```
var urls : [NSURL] = [NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")!,NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")!,NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/03_GURU_JI_TERI_REHMAT_Singer_Sada_Thakur.mp3")!]

urls.append( NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")! )

//retrieving
var url = urls[0]
println(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var urls : [NSURL] = []
urls.append( NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")! )
// to add NSURL's, call urls.append

//retrieving        
var url = urls[0]
println(url)
```

Comment: i tried but it shows error i.e. '[Strings]' is not convertible to '[NSURL]'

Answer (score -1):

I might be wrong as I have no experience in developing so pls correct me if I'm wrong

```
var urls : [NSURL] = ["http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3", "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3" , http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/03_GURU_JI_TERI_REHMAT_Singer_Sada_Thakur.mp3]

urls.append( NSURL(string: "http://trialwebsite.ucoz.com/GurujiHymns/02_BIGDI_MERI_TAQDIR_KO_Singer_Masoom_Thakur.mp3")! )
// to add NSURL's, call urls.append

//retrieving
var url = urls[0]
println(url)
```